# How do i get the bot to edit its own sent message when the user that issued the command reacts to one of the options below?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

so im working on a feature that creates a channel, puts it into a category, sends a message into that channel. All of that is currently working, however, im looking for a way to have the bot listen to reactions to that message by using the awaitReactions feature of discordjs.

Where i am currently at: I have done some research on the matter but i cant really seem to figure it out. 
I have gotten the bot to react to its own message, but i want it to listen to if the user that issued the command reacts to one of the reactions provided below. When the message is reacted to by the user which issued the command, i want the message the bot sent to edit and say something else.

```
    let name =  message.author.username;
    let channel = message.guild.createChannel(name, {
            type: "text",
            permissionOverwrites: [{
                id: message.author,
                deny: ["MANAGE_MESSAGES"],
                allow: ["SEND_MESSAGES", "VIEW_CHANNEL"]
            },
            {
                id: "466764415476432920",
                deny: ["SEND_MESSAGES", "VIEW_CHANNEL"]
            },
            {
                id: "642073025046642708",
                allow: ["VIEW_CHANNEL", "SEND_MESSAGES"]
            },
            {
                id: "569736927427821569",
                allow: ["VIEW_CHANNEL", "SEND_MESSAGES"]
            }]

        }).then(channel => {
            let category = message.guild.channels.find(c => c.name == "Support Area" && c.type == "category");
            if (!category) throw new Error("Category channel does not exist");
            channel.setParent(category.id);
            channel.send(`Life Can Be Ruff! - You’re not alone ${message.author} :heart:
Resources and coping skills while I connect you to a <@&569736927427821569>`).then(reactmessage => { 
    reactmessage.react(""),
    reactmessage.react(""),
    reactmessage.react("")


})
          }).catch(console.error);
```

this is where i am currently at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wait for a specific reaction from a specific user like this:

```
const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return reaction.emoji.name === '' && user.id === message.author.id;
};

message.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] })
   .then(collected => console.log(collected.size))
   .catch(collected => {
   console.log(`Reacted! :D`);
});
```

This would wait for a minute!